# What is the most common term for sand dough?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Recently, [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/why-do-i-need-to-put-sable-dough-in-the-fridge) was asked. The OP created a tag "sable", which I deleted. I thought there was a tag already for these kinds of dough, but apparently, there isn't. I created the tag "sand-dough", thinking this term is a bit more common than "sablé".

What term do you think is correct for this kind of dough?

- sand dough
- sablé
- brisé
- shortcrust
- ... (feel free to suggest your own term)

Comment: And in which English dialect :-)

Comment: Since we usually take the American English as guidelines, I suggest we also use the AE term here.

Comment: That's the thing, @mien.  Not sure there *is* a single well known standard US English culinary term for this, especially outside of trained pastry professionals, which is the only reason I know the word--I took some pro classes.

Answer (score 2):

Sable is (AFAIK) a very specific type of shortcrust pastry, so [shortcrust](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcrust) should be fine if it doesn't already exist - that's a pretty well-known baking term, at least in North America.

On the other hand, low-frequency tags are automatically purged from the system, so it's probably a lot of effort for nothing. Any one of those tags you create will probably disappear very soon. I'd just slap a [dough](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dough) or [pastry](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pastry) on it and be done with it. If we somehow end up getting a ton of questions about sable or shortcrust within the next year, we can manually retag or add a tag at that point.

IMO, at this point in our site's lifetime, that's more or less how *all* new tags should be getting created, i.e. finding something important in common between a bunch of pre-existing questions and *then* adding the tag when it actually has value. Maybe on sites like Stack Overflow it makes sense to create new tags as one-offs because new technologies are constantly being developed and it'll probably get used again. But with cooking, the landscape doesn't change that much or that often; if a tag doesn't already exist yet, it's because it's a subject that's almost never discussed on the site, and probably isn't worth creating a tag for until it's more popular.

Comment: [tag:shortcrust] does not exist, which surprises me a bit.

Comment: Shortcrust might be known way up north, but I never heard it until today, not as a proper noun.  Just as in "that crust is very short."

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: It's actually largely a U.S. term in my experience, not Canadian.

Comment: Just googled "shortcrust"... the first page of results are overwhelmingly British and Australian.

Answer (score 0):

The only ones of those terms that I have heard before they came up in chat discussion today were:

sablé
brisé

I don't know that there is a general term that US home cooks would consider widely recognized for these things at all.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've usually heard "short dough". I think this might be too regional for a good match.